# Filling a form though headless browser

Tags: php, symfony, selenium

Due to integration restrictions, I'm forced to register people through a headless browser because the platform doesn't have an API.

I'm able to get this done on my symfony through selenium and PHP Unit. The callenge is that selenium has to be running all through which I don't believe is ideal.

This is my command:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1366x768x24" selenium-standalone start
```

I was hoping using Symfony process class, I could run the command as in below:

```
public function fillFormAndSubmit($inputs,$url,$form)
{
  $process = new Process('/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1366x768x24" selenium-standalone start');
  //$process = new Process('echo Tecmint is a community of Linux Nerds > /tmp/xvfb-run.log 2> /tmp/xvfb.err');
  $process->run();

  usleep(3000000);
  // executes after the command finishes
  if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
      throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
  }
  $this->webDriver->get($url);
  $body = $this->webDriver->findElement(\WebDriverBy::cssSelector('body'))->sendKeys(array(\WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, 't'));
  $form = $this->webDriver->findElement(\WebDriverBy::className($form));

  foreach ($inputs as $input) {

      if($input['type'] == 'select')
      {
        //PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element_Select::fromElement($input['id'])->selectOptionByValue($input['value']);
        //PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element_Select::fromElement($this->byId('selectMenu'))->selectOptionByValue('t3');
        //$this->select($this->byId($input['id']))->selectOptionByValue($input['value']);
        $select = new \WebDriverSelect($form->findElement(\WebDriverBy::id($input['id'])));
        $select->selectByValue($input['value']);
      }
      elseif($input['type'] == 'checkbox')
      {
        $form->findElement(\WebDriverBy::id($input['id']))->click();
      }
      else {
        //echo $input['id'];
        $form->findElement(\WebDriverBy::id($input['id']))->sendKeys($input['value']);
      }
  }

  $form->submit();
  echo shell_exec('pkill -f selenium-standalone');
  //$this->waitForUserInput();
```

}

However, the shell command doesn't fire when I try to run the service on-demand. Is there a better way of doing this? If not, anyone with an idea of how to get it to work?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `createClient` in a functional test as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#your-first-functional-test You shouldn't need to run selenium at all to fill in a form.

Comment: Isn't this something you could accomplish much simpler with `curl -F`?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, let me investigate both options.